# Missing code in google-api. Unable to locate 'picasa-android-sample' code

Tags: android, picasa, google-api-java-client

I have followed [this](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg-history/8c52d30c2a8e47a5303bd917e3d9413c5b51f430/picasa-android-sample/instructions.html) tutorial to create an app for Picasa android. I downloaded the code from:

> hg clone
>   https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client.samples/ google-api-java-client-samples

Then I struggled very hard to install all the prerequisites. But at the end I found that main code is missing from the Checkout. Tutorial says:

> Click "Browse" next to "Select root directory", find
>   [someDirectory]/google-api-java-client-samples/picasa-android-sample
>   and click "Next"

I can find `picasa-cmdline-sample` but I can't find `picasa-android-sample` code in `google-api-java-client`

Can any one guide me what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can find the source here:
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/picasa-atom-android-sample/src/com/google/api/client/sample/picasa/PicasaAndroidSample.java?repo=samples&r=cc719e03305e81ce2683779b242fd6457efff0d0

And put it (and the whole model folder)in the google-api-java-client-samples folder.